# pip error on django-ftp-deploy

Tags: python, django, deployment, ftp

```
 sudo apt-get install django-ftp-deploy
```

has this error:

```
 requests 2.18.4 has requirement certifi>=2017.4.17, but you'll have
 certifi 0.0.8 which is incompatible
```

I tried to 
    sudo pip install --upgrade requests

but this again has an error message:

```
django-ftp-deploy 2.0.0 has requirement certifi==0.0.8, but you'll have 
certifi 2018.4.16 which is incompatible.
```

When I try to upgrade the django package

```
 sudo apt-get install --upgrade django-ftp-deploy
```

it once again has an requirement conflict.

How can I solve this conflict?

Comment: why are you using `sudo apt-get` and not `pip`?

Comment: Of course you are right, this was the command I used:

     `sudo pip install --upgrade django-ftp-deploy`

Comment: Could I suggest you use a virtual environment.  That way you will not need to use sudo.  `django-ftp-deploy` looks quite out of date.  It seems to need django 1.7 (http://django-ftp-deploy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) so you may find you need to install django1.7 and go from there.

Comment: Is there maybe a more simple way to deploy?